# Parsley multistep form - validate on click next step

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

I am trying to achieve a multistep form where the next step is only shown when the current is valid.

I am trying to trigger the validation script on click on the next button. My function looks like this:

```
function createNextButton($form, options) {
    return $('<a />')
        .prop('href', '#')
        .addClass('application__btn application__btnNext')
        .html('>')
        .click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var curIndex = $('.application--stateVisible').attr('data-tab');
            if ($('.applicationJS__validate').parsley().validate({group: 'block-' + curIndex})) {
                showNextTab($form, options);
            }

        });
}
```

My HTML Form looks like this:

```
<form data-parsley-validate="data-parsley-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="field" class="application applicationJS__validate" action="/" method="post" novalidate="">
<fieldset data-tab="1" class="applicationJS__fieldset _9 1 _application--stateVisible" style="display: block;">
    <legend class="_legend _application__legend">Persönliche Daten</legend>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 ">
            <div class="_field">
                <input data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="Dieses Feld muss ausgefüllt werden!" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="Straße/Hausnr.*" class="_input  " id="_field_1" type="text" name="tx__pi1[field][]" value="" data-parsley-group="block-1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_fieldwrap _tab_navigation">
        <a href="#" class="application__btn application__btnNext">&gt;</a>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset data-tab="2" class="applicationJS__fieldset _11 2" style="display: none;">
    <legend class="_legend _application__legend">Organisatorisches</legend>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="_field">
                <select data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="Dieses Feld muss ausgefüllt werden!" data-parsley-trigger="change" class="_select  " id="_field_2" name="tx__pi1[field][]" data-parsley-group="block-2">
                    <option value="">Üben Sie eine Nebenbeschäftigung aus?</option>
                    <option value="Nein">Nein</option>
                    <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_fieldwrap _tab_navigation">
        <a href="#" class="application__btn application__btnPrev">&lt;</a>
        <a href="#" class="application__btn application__btnNext">&gt;</a>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I am including my js in the footer. The application.js includes the functions with the createNextButton():

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="application/parsley.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="application/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Maybe somebody has a hint for me.

Comment: can you show the part of application.js, where you call the function createNextButton?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a single form for all of the steps, then what you need to do is create validation groups, one for each step, and validate the group you are currently on.

> data-parsley-group: Assign a group to a field for specific group validation. eg: data-parsley-group="signup". This way, you could only validate a portion of a form and not all the fields. Can be multiple. eg: data-parsley-group='["foo", "bar"]'

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#usage-field